# PHP class function __construct passing property issue

Tags: php, class, pdo

After research on php classes, I am stuck on why my php class will only work one way and not as I expect. I expect to be able to pass the ini file location when creating a new instance of the class.
The following code throws a parse_ini_file open file error.

```
class MyPDO extends PDO {
    public function __construct($file){
      //print $file returns '/usr/local/www/config/db.ini'
      if (!$settings = parse_ini_file($file, TRUE)) throw new 
      exception('Unable to open ' . $file . '.');

      $dns = $settings['database']['driver'] . ':host=' . 
      $settings['database']['host'];

      parent::__construct($dns, $settings['database']['username'], 
      $settings['database']['password']);
    }
}

try {
    $conn_login = new MyPDO('/usr/local/www/config/db.ini');
    $conn_login->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}
catch(PDOException $e){
    echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Yet the following will work as expected;

```
class MyPDO extends PDO{
    public function __construct($file){
        $file = '/usr/local/www/config/db.ini'; //added to make work
        if (!$settings = parse_ini_file($file, TRUE)) throw new 
        exception('Unable to open ' . $file . '.');

        $dns = $settings['database']['driver'] . ':host=' . 
        $settings['database']['host'];

        parent::__construct($dns, $settings['database']['username'], 
        $settings['database']['password']);
    }
}

try {
    $conn_login = new MyPDO('/usr/local/www/config/db.ini');
    $conn_login->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}
catch(PDOException $e){
    echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: What is the exact error? Try removing the `throw` to get a real error.

Comment: Looking at the code I can't see a reason for it not to accept the parameter.

Comment: I've try your code here and work

Comment: The error is "Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: Unable to open . in filename"

Comment: I am on PHP Version 7.0.26

Comment: error without throw is "error":"An error occurred while connecting to the database. The error reported by the server was: could not find driver" Which would make sense at it isn't reading the ini file.